# Canoe and Matlab/Simulink communication

Tags: matlab, simulink, communication, canoe

I want to establish communication between CANoe and MATLAB/Simulink. I want to extract the frames from ECUs in CANoe and read them in Simulink, but I can't find the block that can do this. I have only found a block that can extract the data without the frame.

How can I connect CANoe to MATLAB/SimuLink in order to communicate?

Answer (score 0):

Here is Vector (CANoe producers) documentation about it:
[Using MATLAB with CANoe](https://cdn.vector.com/cms/content/know-how/_application-notes/AN-IND-1-007_Using_MATLAB_with_CANoe.pdf)

Section 2.3 points out how there is a specific simulink library for it that comprehends both sources and sinks.

Section 3.1 guides you through the setup and section 3.2 through the execution.

Comment: I read this documentation but I didn't find how I can get the frame from CANoe to simulik I tried to use all the blocks in simulink but I get just the data

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "frame" and "I get just the data". But if you mean you want to access the signals in a message according to their dbc definition then there's an option in the Message Input Block to output "Bus signal" as opposed to "Vector" (which is just the array of raw data).
[image]

You can then use a bus selector to access the signals.
[image]